# Check current process template in TFS

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, alm, tfs-process-template

I have a project that I don't remember the process template version I'm using because I didn't pay attention to the version on creation. How can I check the process template version of a project hosted on Team Foundation Service (http://visualstudio.com)?

I was able to find the differences between the process templates themselves:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms400752%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms400752%28v=vs.120%29.aspx

But I was unable to find a comparison of the individual process template versions. Can someone point the diferences between Microsoft Visual Studio Scrum from version 1 through version 3 for example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The process template is automatically upgraded to **latest**. So whatever version you started with, the current process template is **latest**. Currently,

- If Scrum, 3.0
- If MSF for Agile, 7.0
- If MSF for CMMI, 7.0

btw, IF you don't know the process template then, It can be known by observation.

Comment: See also: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dstfs/archive/2013/09/27/determining-process-template-of-an-existing-team-project-in-tfs-2012.aspx

Answer (score 3):

The ProcessGuidance option works only if you have integration with Sharepoint.

So if you don't have the integration you can use the sql query in this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dstfs/archive/2013/09/27/determining-process-template-of-an-existing-team-project-in-tfs-2012.aspx) to find out the process template. You need to run it against the TFS db.

Answer (score 2):

Under Documents/ProcessGuidance there is a document called ProcessGuidance.html click on it and it will say what type it is.